# How to display web content correctly even if the browser is not maximized?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

My problem is that my web site's content (design) "breaks" when it's not maximized ...

I want it to be like most of the others web sites (e.g. facebook) ...

So when the site is not maximized, that the design don't fall apart, but instead it stay "static" no matter how much I change the height/width of the browser manually.

Does anyone have an idea (I'm looking for some code :D) ?

Regards,

Comment: You need to learn CSS.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that now ... do you have any key words to share ?

Comment: `max-width` and media queries.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into a css framework like bootstrap. If you follow their styles you get a lot of responsive resize features for free.

http://getbootstrap.com/